# Connect SQL Server with RStudio and access data in the environment

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi

I have a connection to a mysql server like this:

```
mydb <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = MySQL(),
  host = "host",
  port = 1111,
  user = "user_1",
  password = "password",
  dbname = "database_name"
)
```

and then I do queries to that data table using this code

```
query1 <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from table_1"), n = Inf)
```

so the result is that I have a query1 table in the R environment.

Now I have other databases in SQL Server, so I'm trying to do the same. I'm establishing the connection doing this:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "server",
                 Database = "database_2",
                 UID = "user_2",
                 PWD = "password",
                 Port = 2222)
```

and it seems that works, because in the Connection tab appears the database, but when I navigate and try to see the data an error occurs. Besides this, I'm looking for functions that do the same like the previous (`fetch` with `dbSendQuery`), having this way the data frames available in the environment.

Comment: 1) Use `dbGetQuery` rather than combining `fetch` and `dbSendQuery`. 2) You may need to use other drivers depending on what you have available. If you have [Microsoft ODBC Driver 17](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)  installed you can use `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` for example.

Comment: *"an error occurs"* ... please don't keep it secret, which error? Please include the literal text of the error as well as the expression that triggers it in a code block.

Comment: Using dbGetQuery I get this error:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"OdbcDriver", "missing"’

I'm still using odbc() as the first argument, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem using this code:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 Server = "server",
                 Database = "database_2",
                 UID = "user_2",
                 PWD = "password",
                 Port = 2222)
```

So the problem was in the Driver.